# No files emitted Warning. Seems to recognize compiler though

Tags: coverity

During the build, I am expecting cov-emit.exe to get called for these C files compiled using aampc.exe.  It seems to recognize the aampc compiler since it says "COMPILING".  Could it still be that the compiler is not recognized?  Thanks for any help.

Here is a snippet for 2 of the files so you can see what is in the build-log.txt file:

2021-07-28T15:22:43.189188Z|cov-translate|204916|output|>
2021-07-28T15:22:43.282923Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: "c:\localapps\msys\1.0\bin\echo.exe"
2021-07-28T15:22:43.376446Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: "C:\localapps\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe"
2021-07-28T15:22:43.471298Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: "c:\localapps\msys\1.0\bin\echo.exe"
2021-07-28T15:22:43.600730Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aampc.exe -c =a-noupper -I../../GSW/source/ac -O2 -w2 -l ../../GSW/source/ui/uimprog.c =a-list=obj/ui/uimprog.lis =a-object=obj/ui/uimprog.obj
2021-07-28T15:22:43.710078Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aampcc @C:\Users\userrabz\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2 -I../../GSW/source/ac
2021-07-28T15:22:44.768043Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c move /Y ....\GSW\source\ui\uimprog.lis ....\GSW\source\ui\uimprog.clis
2021-07-28T15:22:45.003488Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\macasm "C:\views\surfmob\GB_GRAM_3_2\GSW\build../../GSW/source/ui/uimprog.asm" -in_macro c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aamp5 -list -cross_reference -instr -l -noupper -list=obj/ui/uimprog.lis -object=obj/ui/uimprog.obj
2021-07-28T15:22:45.182336Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c move /Y ....\GSW\source\ui\uimprog.clis obj\ui\uimprog.lis
2021-07-28T15:22:45.395191Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> CWD: C:\views\surfmob\GB_GRAM_3_2\GSW\build
2021-07-28T15:22:45.395191Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> COMPILING: "C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis\bin\cov-translate.exe" c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aampc.exe -c =a-noupper -I../../GSW/source/ac  -O2 -w2 -l ../../GSW/source/ui/uimprog.c =a-list=obj/ui/uimprog.lis =a-object=obj/ui/uimprog.obj
2021-07-28T15:22:45.395191Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> OUTPUT_FILE: pipe:\.\pipe\cov-log-5ff163dd5238b84826969c9de92e1a35.s
2021-07-28T15:22:45.637350Z|cov-translate|200900|output|> Using cached template compiler configuration instance C:/Users/userrabz/coverity-idirs/DRS/emit/CRM25528/config/ad1734263e4f13355ef9c06230b585b3/coverity_config.xml
2021-07-28T15:22:45.652972Z|cov-translate|200900|output|> COV_TRANSLATE EXPANDED ARGS: "-c" "=a-noupper" "-I../../GSW/source/ac"  "-O2" "-w2" "-l" "../../GSW/source/ui/uimprog.c" "=a-list=obj/ui/uimprog.lis" "=a-object=obj/ui/uimprog.obj"
2021-07-28T15:22:45.684216Z|cov-translate|200900|output|> [WARNING] Invalid gxx version specification: Empty version number. Defaulting to version 3.2.0
2021-07-28T15:22:45.715458Z|cov-translate|200900|output|>
2021-07-28T15:22:45.777943Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: "c:\localapps\msys\1.0\bin\echo.exe"
2021-07-28T15:22:45.845650Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: "C:\localapps\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe"
2021-07-28T15:22:45.940491Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: "c:\localapps\msys\1.0\bin\echo.exe"
2021-07-28T15:22:46.065464Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aampc.exe -c =a-noupper -I../../GSW/source/ac  -O2 -w2 -l ../../GSW/source/ui/uimerase.c =a-list=obj/ui/uimerase.lis =a-object=obj/ui/uimerase.obj
2021-07-28T15:22:46.178008Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aampcc @C:\Users\userrabz\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2 -I../../GSW/source/ac
2021-07-28T15:22:47.486879Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c move /Y ....\GSW\source\ui\uimerase.lis ....\GSW\source\ui\uimerase.clis
2021-07-28T15:22:47.706457Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\macasm "C:\views\surfmob\GB_GRAM_3_2\GSW\build../../GSW/source/ui/uimerase.asm" -in_macro c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aamp5 -list -cross_reference -instr -l -noupper -list=obj/ui/uimerase.lis -object=obj/ui/uimerase.obj
2021-07-28T15:22:47.856727Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> EXECUTING: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c move /Y ....\GSW\source\ui\uimerase.clis obj\ui\uimerase.lis
2021-07-28T15:22:48.045314Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> CWD: C:\views\surfmob\GB_GRAM_3_2\GSW\build
2021-07-28T15:22:48.045314Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> COMPILING: "C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis\bin\cov-translate.exe" c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aampc.exe -c =a-noupper -I../../GSW/source/ac  -O2 -w2 -l ../../GSW/source/ui/uimerase.c =a-list=obj/ui/uimerase.lis =a-object=obj/ui/uimerase.obj
2021-07-28T15:22:48.045314Z|cov-internal-capture|185068|info|> OUTPUT_FILE: pipe:\.\pipe\cov-log-5ff163dd5238b84826969c9de92e1a35.s
2021-07-28T15:22:48.280087Z|cov-translate|198032|output|> Using cached template compiler configuration instance C:/Users/userrabz/coverity-idirs/DRS/emit/CRM25528/config/ad1734263e4f13355ef9c06230b585b3/coverity_config.xml
2021-07-28T15:22:48.296829Z|cov-translate|198032|output|> COV_TRANSLATE EXPANDED ARGS: "-c" "=a-noupper" "-I../../GSW/source/ac"  "-O2" "-w2" "-l" "../../GSW/source/ui/uimerase.c" "=a-list=obj/ui/uimerase.lis" "=a-object=obj/ui/uimerase.obj"
2021-07-28T15:22:48.312450Z|cov-translate|198032|output|> [WARNING] Invalid gxx version specification: Empty version number. Defaulting to version 3.2.0
2021-07-28T15:22:48.328072Z|cov-translate|198032|output|>

Answer (score 0):

As the question focuses on the meaning of this log output, I'll do the same.

The presence of the `COMPILING` line indicates that `cov-build` recognizes that `aampc.exe` is a compiler (based on its executable path name), and has handed one of its command lines to `cov-translate` for further processing.

However, `cov-translate` seems to be confused about what the command line means.  First, it warns about its inability to query the GCC compiler version number; I don't know what `aampc.exe` is, but if it is not a GCC derivative then `cov-configure` may have been given bad information.  The absence of any further output from `cov-translate` means it did not see any compilation and so did nothing.  (That would be correct behavior if the compiler was being invoked to do something like preprocessing or linking only, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  aampc compiler is a "GNU C compiler".  On a different program using a different build tool (but with the same compiler configuration and the same compiler (aampc)), I am able to get cov-emit.exe to get called and Coverity analyzes the files correctly and shows where the issues are in the C files.  Here is a snippet from that build-log.txt file:

Comment: Thanks for the information.  aampc compiler is a "GNU C compiler".  On a different program using a different build tool (but with the same compiler configuration and the same compiler (aampc)), I am able to get cov-emit.exe to get called and Coverity analyzes the files correctly and shows where the issues are in the C files.  That too give the same version number warning.  Here is a snippet from that build-log.txt file:  2021-08-02T13:09:35.777389Z|cov-internal-capture|19084|info|> COMPILING: "C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis\bin\cov-translate.exe"

Comment: c:\AAMP_Tools\aampc\bin\aampc.exe -c =a-noupper -I../source/bs -O2 -w2 ../source/rp/rppreccctr.c =a-list=bin/rp/rppreccctr.lis =a-object=bin/rp/rppreccctr.obj
2021-08-02T13:09:35.777389Z|cov-internal-capture|19084|info|> OUTPUT_FILE: pipe:\\.\pipe\cov-log-09441756df0a64bb4153aaca27f9a7b9.s

Comment: 2021-08-02T13:09:35.933603Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> Using cached template compiler configuration instance C:/Users/userrabz/coverity-idirs/ASR_004/emit/CRM25528/config/ad1734263e4f13355ef9c06230b585b3/coverity_config.xml
2021-08-02T13:09:35.949223Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> COV_TRANSLATE EXPANDED ARGS: "-c" "=a-noupper" "-I../source/bs" "-O2" "-w2" "../source/rp/rppreccctr.c" "=a-list=bin/rp/rppreccctr.lis" "=a-object=bin/rp/rppreccctr.obj"

Comment: 2021-08-02T13:09:35.949223Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> [WARNING] Invalid gxx version specification: Empty version number. Defaulting to version 3.2.0
2021-08-02T13:09:35.964845Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> [WARNING] Argument not recognized by Coverity compiler: =a-noupper
2021-08-02T13:09:35.964845Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> [WARNING] Switch not recognized by Coverity compiler: -w2
2021-08-02T13:09:35.964845Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> [WARNING] Argument not recognized by Coverity compiler: =a-list=bin/rp/rppreccctr.lis

Comment: 2021-08-02T13:09:35.980467Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> [STATUS] Compiling ..\source\rp\rppreccctr.c
2021-08-02T13:09:35.980467Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> "C:/Program Files/Coverity/Coverity Static Analysis/bin/cov-emit.exe" --emit_pch_dependencies --dir= ... (deleted stuff...just showing cov-emit is called)
2021-08-02T13:09:36.261409Z|cov-translate|14304|output|> Emit for file 'C:/views/ASR3_7_004/GPS_SOFTWARE/source/rp/rppreccctr.c' complete.

Comment: @BaeRich You should edit your question to add the additional detail there instead of in comments.  Also, have a look at the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to format log output as preformatted text.  Those will make it easier to read that output.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your compiler entry in coverity_config.xml.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.  The problem was that Coverity does not emit files when compiled with the -l option.  Strange since all this does is create an information only file with a .clis extension.